# Access Denied :Unauthorised ExCeption

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

The following error occurred in my project, can anyone tell me how to solve this exception?

> Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)) in windows phone 8.1.

I have this code:

```
using (IRandomAccessStream readStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))




        StorageFile file = usertoken ;
        try
        {
            if (file != null)
            {
                using (IRandomAccessStream readStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
                {
                    using (DataReader dataReader = new DataReader(readStream))
                    {
                        UInt64 size = readStream.Size;

                        UInt32 numBytesLoaded = await dataReader.LoadAsync((UInt32)size);
                        string fileContent = dataReader.ReadString(numBytesLoaded);
                        return (bool)true;
                        // NotifyUser(String.Format("The following text was read from '{0}' using a stream:{1}{2}", file.Name, Environment.NewLine, fileContent), NotifyType.StatusMessage);

                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return (bool)false;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return (bool)false;
        }
```

Comment: first question: Are you sure the user running the program have read permission on the file?

Comment: this code isn't scoped properly within a `using` block. Best to fix that first.

Comment: yeah,,bt how to check that permission m not getting,please clerify..

Comment: i fix that using block but again i get same exception..

Comment: How did you get the StorageFile? Where from?

Comment: i have already created that file

Comment: usertoken = await IForIndiaisoStore.CreateFileAsync("usertoken.txt", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
var stream = await usertoken.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);

Comment: IForIndiaisoStore = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

Comment: first i created folder name:IForIndiaisoStore

Comment: then created File name:usertoken.txt

Comment: but i got the exception while i tried to open that file..Exception:access denied

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following permissions as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/permissions?tabs=windows#code-try-0):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```